# why model.findOneAndUpdate() returns null in this program?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**In the below program when i run with postman, it returns `null` value as output. i tried but i couldnt fix it.** for all Params value it returns not found as result. I understand filter part is not working. Unable to fix.I tried in postman as follows:`localhost:8000/update/:rani@gmail.com`.this email id exists in the created db

```js
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  studentName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  confirm: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  section: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  age: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  DOB: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
  },
  bloodGroup: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  parentsName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  parentsContactnumber: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  studentEmail: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const studentInfomodel = mongoose.model("studentInfo", studentSchema);
app.put("/update/:studentEmail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let upstudentEmail = req.params.studentEmail;
    let upstudentName = req.body.studentName;
    let upsection = req.body.section;
    console.log(upstudentEmail, upstudentName, upsection)
    //find and update
    let result = await studentInfomodel.findOneAndUpdate({
      studentEmail: upstudentEmail
    }, {
      $set: {
        studentName: upstudentName,
        section: upsection
      }
    }, {
      new: true
    })
    console.log(result);
    if (result == null) {
      res.send("nothing found")
    } else {
      res.send(result)
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);

  }
});
```

Comment: if you're using postman can you please confirm the url , `localhost:8000/update/:rani@gmail.com` if this is the url I think it should be this instead `localhost:8000/update/:studentEmail` and you will see that there's a `params`  input box below you can type the mail there.

Comment: @KaranFulare :thanks when i changed the URL to localhost:8000/update/rani@gmail.com it works. but its not updating in db